# How to list the symbolic links with sftp?

Tags: sftp, symlink, ls

Our hosting provider does not allow `ssh`-access (because security), but lets us upload files and manipulate directories via `sftp`. (The only other choice is through "cpanel").

`sftp` is good enough to allow *creating* the symbolic links, but not good enough to properly list them. For example:

```
sftp> symlink 500 rwu
sftp> ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 foo bar  3 May 22 16:27 rwu
```

That is, I can see the *fact* that "`rwu`" is a symlink, but I can not see to *what*. At least, not by default. Is there some "hidden" option to the entire `sftp`-client or its `ls`-command, that would list symlinks properly -- the way the real `ls(1)` would?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The OpenSSH SFTP client](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/sftp-client.c?rev=1.126&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) does not currently support this.

> ```
> #ifdef notyet
> char *
> do_readlink(struct sftp_conn *conn, const char *path)
> {
>     …
> }
> #endif
> ```

This is the only occurrence of `SSH_FXP_READLINK` in the OpenSSH source code. I don't know why this is commented out or what it would take to make it work. The only relevant message I can find on the OpenSSH mailing list is [a patch from 2002](https://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=103651326517135&w=2) that wasn't adopted.

So your only option is to use a different SFTP client, such as [SSHFS](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: FileZilla cannot display link target either. +1 anyway

Comment: Some versions of `curl` can do sftp too. If you use the url of the directory it will show the typical `ls -l` output with `->` for symbolic links.